# Python C extension: Extract parameter from the engine

Tags: python, c++, c, python-c-extension

I would like to use Python to perform Mathematics tests on my functions. A typical program that can gain access to Python is this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Python.h>
int RunTests()
{
    Py_Initialize();

    PyRun_SimpleString("a=5");
    PyRun_SimpleString("b='Hello'");
    PyRun_SimpleString("c=1+2j");
    PyRun_SimpleString("d=[1,3,5,7,9]");

    //question here

    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

My question is: How can I extract the parameters `a,b,c,d` to `PyObject`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PyRun_SimpleString()` executes the code in the context of the `__main__` module. You can retrieve a reference to this module using `PyImport_AddModule()`, get the globals dictionary from this module and lookup variables:

```
PyObject *main = PyImport_AddModule("__main__");
PyObject *globals = PyModule_GetDict(main);
PyObject *a = PyDict_GetItemString(globals, "a");
```

Instead of using this approach, you might be better off creating a new `globals` dictionary and using `PyRun_String()` to execute code in the context of that `globals` dict:

```
PyObject *globals = PyDict_New();
PyObject *a = PyRun_String("5", Py_single_input, globals, globals);
```

This way, you don't need to first store the result of your expression in some variable and then extract it from the global scope of `__main__`.  You can still use variables to store intermediate results, which can then be extracted from `globals` as above.

Comment: This is throwing a SIGSEGV - segmentation fault exception at `a` when debugging. Are there any other calls I should do beside this one?

Comment: Just found out that `PyEval_GetLocals` is returning `NULL`! Would you know why? The engine is running according to the code I provided.

Comment: I'm sorry. Your code doesn't work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40046330/python-c-extension-pyeval-getlocals-returns-null

Comment: Sorry, I didn't test this.  It looks like you don't have an active frame outside of the `PyRun_SimpleString()` calls.  I edited the answer with code that should work in that case as well (which I again did not test).

Comment: Thank you! The updated code works. Could you provide a sample for your suggestion?

Comment: I've updated the answer with an example of `PyRun_String()`.