# Python C Extension: PyEval_GetLocals() returns NULL

Tags: python, c++, c, python-c-extension, python-extensions

I need to read local variables from Python in C/C++. When I try to `PyEval_GetLocals`, I get a NULL. This happens although Python is initialized. The following is a minimal example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Python.h>

Py_Initialize();
PyRun_SimpleString("a=5");
PyObject *locals = PyEval_GetLocals();
std::cout<<locals<<std::endl; //prints NULL (prints 0)
Py_Finalize();
```

In [the manual](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/reflection.html#c.PyEval_GetLocals), it says that it returns NULL if no frame is running, but... there's a frame running!

**What am I doing wrong?**

I'm running this in Debian Jessie.

Comment: @martineau But even globals returns NULL! Does this mean this is not the appropriate way to get the variables there? Because I already accepted an answer about that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40041498/python-c-extension-extract-parameter-from-the-engine/40041694#40041694

Comment: @martineau verifying that `PyRun_SimpleString()` is working is very easy. I can print stuff and assign stuff and it works. Would you suggest a fix for that example code?

Comment: @martineau That also returns NULL. I mentioned that in my first response to you :-)

Comment: @martineau Printing `a` with the command you provided works and prints `5`. Also printing `locals()` with `print(locals())` prints a `dict` that contains `a`.

Comment: @martineau :( ...

Comment: I updated my answer on the other question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the right way to access variables in the scope is:

```
Py_Initialize();
PyObject *main = PyImport_AddModule("__main__");
PyObject *globals = PyModule_GetDict(main);
PyObject *a = PyDict_GetItemString(globals, "a");
std::cout<<globals<<std::endl; //Not NULL
Py_Finalize();
```

Comment: Side-note: This leaks a reference; the program will clean up on exit, but if you need to debug reference leaks, this will be one more leak to wade through. Simplest fix is to change `PyDict_GetItem(globals, PyUnicode_FromString("a"));` to `PyDict_GetItemString(globals, "a");` which is logically identical, except it manages creating and releasing the `PyUnicode` object for you, ensuring it's properly `DECREF`-ed.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thank you very much! This is an important note, and I updated my code accordingly :) I hope there's no more leaks there.

Comment: Please update your answer so it's doing essentially same thing as what's in your question. Also, the `PyModule_GetDict(main)` seems like it would cause a compile error since `main` is undefined.

Comment: @martineau Are you sure that `main` is undefined?

Comment: @martineau The code in the answer replaces the code in the question. The purpose is extracting a variable from the Python frame.